# Composer update error with Laravel 5 - 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I needed to customize a package I found on packagist, so I cloned the repo on github and updated my `composer.json` file to get the dependency from there instead.

Now when I run `composer update` I get the following:

```
[4.5MB/0.34s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[4.8MB/1.57s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
[248.7MB/16.88s]   - Removing serverfireteam/blog (master)
[113.1MB/17.54s] Writing lock file
[113.1MB/17.55s] Generating autoload files

Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in C:\Users\Tim\Code\Laravel\config\excel.php on line 174
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in C:\Users\Tim\Code\Laravel\config\excel.php on line 174
[113.4MB/18.22s] Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in C:\Users\Tim\Code\Laravel\config\excel.php on line 174
```

I reveresed the change, and ran `composer update' again and get the following message:

```
[4.4MB/0.33s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[4.7MB/1.48s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
[258.9MB/15.11s] Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
[258.9MB/15.11s]
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
    - serverfireteam/blog master requires illuminate/support ~5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - serverfireteam/blog dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
    - Installation request for serverfireteam/blog dev-master -> satisfiable by serverfireteam/blog[master].

[113.9MB/15.48s] Memory usage: 113.9MB (peak: 259.06MB), time: 15.48s
```

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Does `serverfireteam/blog dev-master` require laravel 5.1 and the other packages require 5 when I'm trying to roll back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your own comment @TimothyBuktu, `serverfireteam/blog` requires laravel 5.1.

You'll want to lock the version of `serverfireteam/blog` to `dev-master#c0039d3ade67503d674093f3a56d7b1540ae958d` in your `composer.json`, which is the last commit before the requirement of laravel was bumped to 5.1

Alternatively if you still want to receive updates for the package, you'll need to update your application to laravel 5.1. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade

Comment: I've changed my `composer.json` to :
    ` "serverfireteam/blog": "dev-master#c0039d3ade67503d674093f3a56d7b1540ae958d" `
  
     but still having the same problem.

Comment: try running `composer update --lock` then `composer install`

Comment: I was having the same problem with the Excel class not found. Running composer install corrected the issue for me.

Answer (score 16):

delete config/excel.php and re-publish it.
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider`

Comment: this save my day!! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

mm Xl's answer is excellent!

But after version 3.1 (included), the command is changed to the following one:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

To see this part on docs: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/laravel-excel-docs/blob/develop/3.1/getting-started/installation.md